# I have problem to send multiple users id into database using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner, Actually, I am sending multiple users id into the database but I want to send user-id one by on how to do it? please help me thanks.

Does anybody have an idea?

EXAMPLE HERE

multi user-id is sending into the database like this but I don't want like this

```
          user_id      user_access_id    
            1        |  2,3,4,5      
            2        |  9,5
            3        |   6,5
```

I want Like this

```
       user_id      user_access_id    
            1        |  2
            1        |  3
            1        |  4
            1        |  5
            2        |  9
            2        |  5
            3        |  5
            3        |  6
```

**Controller**

```
     public function adduseraction(REQUEST $request)
  {  
     $useradd=$request->get('userid');
     $checkid=$request->get('multiusersid');   
     $user=Users_permissions::create([             
     'user_id'=>$useradd,
     'user_Access_id'=> implode($checkid, ','),
     ]);   
     return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Users has been assigned');



   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below.

```
public function adduseraction(REQUEST $request) {  

    $useradd=$request->get('userid');
    $checkid=$request->get('multiusersid');

    $array = array();
    foreach($checkid as $id){
        $array[] = array('user_id'=>$useradd,'user_Access_id'=>$id);
    }

    $user=Users_permissions::insert($array);

    return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Users has been assigned');
}
```

Comment: Better way is to make relation with user and user permission and do it by using relationship :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function adduseraction(Request $request)
  {  
     for ($i=0; $i<count($request->multiusersid); $i++) { 
        $user=Users_permissions::create([             
            'user_id'=>$request->userid,
            'user_Access_id'=> $request->multiusersid[$i],
        ]);   
    }

    return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Users has been assigned');
   }
```